# Seeking plugin for displaying keyboard shortcuts in Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

I'm looking for a webstorm plugin that would help me remember keyboard shortcuts. I know for a fact that this plugin exists for IntelliJ, it displays the right-shortcut every time we perform an action without using shortcuts, but I didn't find any thing like this for webstorm?

If you know (and understand) what I'm talking about, can you tell me what plugin could help me with it?

Thanks for your time,

Fabien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Key Promoter](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4455) plug-in is compatible with WebStorm, you can also use `Help` | `Find Action` and type the action name, shortcut will be displayed on the right.